# how to create a insert statement for values returned by a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a following select query:

```
select productid from product where productid not in (select productid from userproduct)
```

which gives me following output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Now, i have another table userproduct which conatins following columns:

```
userid
productid
updatetime
author
```

I want to create following insert statements through sql:

```
insert into userproduct values(100,1,getdate(),'abc');
insert into userproduct values(100,2,getdate(),'abc');
insert into userproduct values(100,3,getdate(),'abc');
insert into userproduct values(100,4,getdate(),'abc');
insert into userproduct values(200,1,getdate(),'abc');
insert into userproduct values(200,2,getdate(),'abc');
insert into userproduct values(200,3,getdate(),'abc');
insert into userproduct values(200,4,getdate(),'abc');
```

Just for demo purpose I have used 4 values. But actually, i'll get hundreds of values. I can't create insert statements for all of them.
Is there any way to create the insert statements automatically?

Comment: So you need one set of `userId = 100` and another set of `userId = 200` for each `productId`?

Comment: You want to make insert script for each user with the combination of `productid` but there is some lagging as how many users do you have and is that maintained in another separate table ??

Comment: Yeah, for now, i want it for only two users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an insert select statement. Cross join your results with the users table.

```
insert into userproduct (userid, productid, updatetime, author)
  select u.userid, p.productid, getdate(), 'abc'
  from product p
  cross join users u
  where p.productid not in (select productid from userproduct) ;
```

(You can of course add add criteria to restrict this to certain users, e.g. `and u.userid in (100,200)`.)

(Or replace `cross join users u` with `cross join (select 100 as userid union all select 200) u`, if you don't want to access the users table for some reason.)

Comment: This one looks good to me. as I can use it for more users if required. All I need to do is add filter criteria for selected users. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If 100 & 200 are only two distinct userids and 'abc' is the author value always, then

```
insert into userproduct (userid,productid,updatetime,author)
select 100,productid,getdate(),'abc' from product where productid not in (select productid from userproduct) 
Union
select 200,productid,getdate(),'abc' from product where productid not in(select productid from userproduct)
```

Comment: Thanks, Kapil. This is fine. But it can be optimized a little bit. We can merge it in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: If you have limited `userid` to insert and not maintained in the table. you can use `CROSS JOIN` with static `userid`s as below and you can add few more if needed:

```
INSERT INTO userproduct (userid,productid,updatetime,author)
SELECT x.userid, p.productid, getdate(),'abc' 
FROM product p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT userid FROM (values(100),(200)) x (userid)) x
WHERE productid NOT IN(SELECT productid FROM userproduct)
```

We can use `tablename` in the `CROSS JOIN` if users are maintained in any table.

Comment: Thannks. I have usersid in another table. I'll use cross join with that table.